# Reactのフックについて

Tags: reactjs, typescript

現在、Reactベースのアプリ開発をしています。
多くの入門書やページでは、子コンポーネントから親コンポーネントのstateを変更する際、以下のように値をセットするだけの関数を別に定義しているものが大抵なのですが、set関数自体を渡すことになにか問題があるのでしょうか？

```
const ComponentA = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>();

  handleValue = (value: string) => {
    setValue(value);
  }

  return(
    <ComponentB handleValue={handleValue} />
  );
}

const ComponentB = (props: {handleValue: (value: string} => void}) => {
  // 略
}
```

Comment: 「多くの入門書やページ」とありますが、具体的な書類名やページのサイトのURLをあげてくれませんか？もしかしたら、書いている内容を勘違いしている可能性もありますので。また、質問のコードは何らかのサイトの引用でしょうか？そうであれば、引用元も明記するようにしてください。

Answer (score 0):

問題ないと思います。
私が現在開発しているプロジェクトではよく見る記法です。